# get Sharepoint List View data in C# without Service Reference

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ssis

I encountered som issue when using Sharepoint LIst Source on an SSIS package (too many redirection...)
My goal is to retrieve (whatever the type of result (xml, rows...) the content of a sharepoint list based on a specific view.
I only have a http://xxxxxx/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx url access.
I currently try this kind of code:

```
        string serviceURL = "https://xxxxx/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
        wr.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        wr.PreAuthenticate = true;
        wr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        wr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        wr.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        //  wr.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 500;

        HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
        Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();
       // StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(str, Encoding.UTF8);

        string xmlData;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            xmlData = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
```

At this point it seems I have no longer error (too many redirection...) but now I'm block to get columns name and value, or xml value containing all data.

Using Web Service connected to the lists.asmx failed too, so I can't use this kind of solution.

Any ideas ?

thanks in advance.
regards,

Comment: Do a web search for "vs asmx refresh"

Comment: Hello jdweng. Sorry for the last answer. I search on web, but found nothing corresponding. did you have a specific resource / url ?

Comment: Do search without the double quotes.

Comment: that's what I'm doing, but this is not a refresh I need, but reading (searching with read not give adequat solution :(
regards

Comment: The mapping must be updated before you can read.  If the mapping between the database and the c# classes are wrong you will never be able to read.  Refreshing the mapping will synchronize the database and the c# classes.

Comment: Dear jdweng. Thanks for your patience. Finally, there was an network hidden authentication that cause error. Now solve by adding a wording as user-agent.
Regards

Comment: The user agent http header specifies the browser so you network firewall was rejecting due the the browser that was being used.